# Deployment synchronization Issue - API Manager 1.8

Tags: deployment, synchronization, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have clusted the WSO2 API Manager 1.8 and implemented deployment synchronization according [to this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM140/SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer) which is given in the WSO2 documentaion. Everything happens to work find except one thing.

Let's assume that we have below 2 instances running API Manager.

192.168.X.123 - API Manager 1

192.168.X.124 - API Manager 2

The problem is once I create and publish an API on API Manager 1 it does appear on API Manager 2 in the publisher. But the particular API does not appear on the API Manager 2 Store.

Also note that I'm using a shared MySQL database for the API Manager cluster(API Manager 1 and 2). I checked the logs but does not contains any error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In our situation, we defined 2 different servers with extra CPU and
>   memory, on these servers we have installed the full WSO2 API Manager
>   and defined the cluster configuration. Everything provisioned via
>   Puppet.
>
> Just a straightforward install, all data-source pointing to one schema
>   in an Oracle database.
>
> And...it is working; Our Developers happy, Operations happy, Architect
>   department happy

From [WSO2 API Manager Clustering configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263825/wso2-api-manager-clustering-configuration/21503663#comment46255735_21503663)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [WSO2 Clustering and Deployment Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/WSO2+Clustering+and+Deployment+Guide). Please check the docs on [Clustering API Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager) and [SVN-based Deployment Synchronizer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/SVN-based+Deployment+Synchronizer)

If all configurations are correct, your API should be displayed in Store once you have ["Published" the API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Create+and+Publish+an+API). It might take some time (may be few minutes) to appear in Store due to indexing etc.